# Why my wp_posts data is so huge?

Tags: posts, database, revisions

My WordPress has only 23 posts but the wp_posts data is over 70MiB. Is it the average size? The Posts I have were created with [WPBakery Visual Composer](http://codecanyon.net/item/visual-composer-page-builder-for-wordpress/full_screen_preview/242431) and has 10 revisions. However, I deleted all the revisions with [Revision Control](https://wordpress.org/plugins/revision-control/) but the wp_posts data size has no change.

**--- update info on Apr 22, 2016 @ 12:12pm --**
**I found the wp_posts data it has over "60000+" rows of data.**

**-- update info on Apr 27th 2016 @ 5:02pm --**
I removed and optimized all the revisions by [Advanced Database Cleaner](https://wordpress.org/plugins/advanced-database-cleaner/). I also changed "`define('WP_POST_REVISIONS', 10 );`" to "`define('WP_POST_REVISIONS', false );`" in **wp-config.php**, but the revision still coming back. ***Is there a way to stop them?***

**-- update info on Apr 28th 2016 @ 3:04pm --**
After hours of research and plugin check, I found the revisions are created by [FeedWordPress](https://wordpress.org/plugins/feedwordpress/). After deactivate the plugin I dont see the new revision again.

Comment: Visual Composer is likely the problem.  There is a very real expense to the convenience of that convenience.

Answer (score 2):

No, that isn't normal for 23 posts.

Note that "posts" is pretty wide concept in modern WordPress. Many things *are* posts without being obvious as such, for example parts of navigation menus.

While 60k entries does sound excessive for a small site, there is no telling without examining actual data to determine which post types it belongs to and if those entries are valid for some purpose or merely broken leftovers.

Comment: I found it also contained 1000+ events. The data size went down to 1.4MiB after I deleted all the revisions with "Advanced Database Cleaner".

Comment: after deleting all the revision on live site the memory usage is back to normal now. :)

Comment: I updated the question. They keep coming even I set the define(WP_POST_REVISIONS', false); in wp-config.php

Answer (score 0):

I don't think Visual Composer is the problem. Have you installed a logging plugin?

Open phpMyAdmin and simply delete them. They are likely a post type you dont use.

You can use the following query

```
DELETE po,pm,tr
    FROM wp_posts po
    LEFT JOIN wp_term_relationships tr
        ON (po.ID = tr.object_id)
    LEFT JOIN wp_postmeta pm
        ON (po.ID = pm.post_id)
    WHERE po.post_type = '{{Suspected post type}}';
```

Make sure you don't remove the posta that are used by your site. Check what post types you use.

Also 'attachment', 'post', 'page', 'revision', ' nav_menu_item' so on are WordPress default - don't remove them.

Comment: Dangerous advice... And entries in wp_postmeta would become obsolete and difficult to filter out after this action.